# Pandas replacing Subset of Dataframe replaces other parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace a subset of a Dataframe by another subset of another dataframe.
Evertyme I run the following code, not only the columns 100:111 are replaced. Instead all of the columns are replaced. Why is that so? To me it doesn`t make any sense.

```
if test_h.iloc[i, s] == 'F150Hz__nT100ms__B0__Pos25__0.8':
        val = test_h.iloc[i, s:s+11]
        test_h_format.iloc[i, 100:111] = val
```

Comment: I also tried different approaches like .loc or doing it manually. 
But the outcome is always the same. 
Maybe I should note, that the dataframe test_h_format is a manipulated copy of test_h

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do. If you could give more detail and a reproducible example that would be good.

Anyway here is how you can replace a subset with another:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mick', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Mary'],
                  'Age': [17, 27, 37, 47]})

other_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Charles', 'Eve', 'Fred', 'Gary'],
                  'Age': [20, 30, 40, 50]})

the_subset = other_df.query('Age < 30') # ie. Charles

# replace df where age less than 20 (Mick) with the subset (Charles)
df.loc[df['Age'] < 20, :] = the_subset
```